# Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension

Tags: php, facebook, apache

I'm trying to run my first facebook php application on my apache server.
It gives error `Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.`. I have added line `extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini and it runs normally in phpStorm ide.
But it still gives error in web browser when I put php files into apache directory and run server manually.

Comment: You have to install the extension and enable in in the php.ini. Also, restart your webserver after having done both.

Comment: It works ok when I run php with phpStorm ide.I have restarted server.

Comment: Did you just uncomment the line in php.ini without checking whether the extension is actually available eg: `path/to/your/www/php/ext/php_curl.dll`, also if your using an ide the ide may be using its own extensions like `path/to/your/ide/php/ext/php_curl.dll` and may also not be using the same php.ini file.

Comment: I have checked that all already, but no result

Comment: also, you must restart apache after changing the php.ini file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in a new php page type:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

in there check to see which php.ini you need to edit.

```
Loaded Configuration File: ________ path to ini file you must edit _______
```

Also, use this page to see if the server thinks curl is enabled. do you see this line:

```
 cURL support   enabled
```

if it is not enabled after editing the ini file and restarting the web server, things depend on how you installed php

this [guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-install-php-on-windows/) looks promising enough

Comment: If you are on Wamp 64bit and you are getting this error, the packaged extension is actually bugged. http://www.morningtime.com/kb/188. This has a fixed php_curl.dll

Comment: @Kelvin looks like the link has changed a little. Could you provide another fix for wamp 64bit, please? I'd be really grateful, I've been struggling a lot with this

Comment: @BujancaMihai - I see the other site has changed. You may be able to get the fixed extension here. Scroll to the bottom and look for fixed curl extensions. http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ I found this link in this forum post. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85716 You may also be able to use the 32 bit version depending on how everything is setup. I hope this works for you. I did not test this.

Answer (score 18):

I was also getting the error. I tried this command.

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

and my problem was resolved.

Comment: Did this and restarted the server (`service apache2 restart`). Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Error:

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension

Solution:

> ;extension=php_curl.dll

1) Remove `;` (comment from begining) in php.ini file and save. If this line is not in file than add this file.

2) Restart appache (XAMPP)

Answer (score 3):

only needs to uncomment extension=php_curl.dll from c:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: @Grant Winney: I am trying to program something with Facebook's PHP SDK.  I followed their documentation, and their example didn't work and threw the error message that is the title of this question.  I did what Yannick posted above, and that fixed the problem.  The person who added comments to the original question was dumb for not posting that as an answer.

Comment: On Linux use `extension=php_curl.so`. Then restart Apache.

Comment: Most likely will need to restart Apache afterward... This fixed it for me, or at least got me to the next exeption anyways :D

Answer (score 2):

I was having same issue with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and PHP 5.6 (LEMP) configuration. This has been resolved by below commands.

*$ sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5.6-curl*

verify the Curl.so file in extension directory
*$ php -i | grep extension_dir* (This will give you path for PHP extension dir)

Verify the curl.in file

*$ sudo vi /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/curl.ini*

It should be

*; configuration for php curl module

; priority=20

extension=curl.so*

Verify the Curl enabled in php

*$ php -i | grep curl*

**output should be;**

cURL support => enabled

cURL Information => 7.35.0

Age => 3

Features

AsynchDNS => Yes

CharConv => No

Debug => No

GSS-Negotiate => Yes

IDN => Yes

IPv6 => Yes

krb4 => No

Largefile => Yes

libz => Yes

NTLM => Yes

NTLMWB => Yes

SPNEGO => No

SSL => Yes

SSPI => No

TLS-SRP => Yes

Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtmp, rtsp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp

Host => x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.1f

ZLib Version => 1.2.8

Restart the php5.6-fpm

*$ sudo service php5.6-fpm restart*

Restart the Nginx

*$ sudo service nginx restart*

This will work :)

Answer (score 1):

i am using wamp on windows 7 64-bit. i have downloaded fixed curl extension version
php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip
from url
http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/
and the issue is resolved.
please keep php version in mind while download extension. I have downloaded this version as i am using php version 5.3.13

Answer (score 0):

Facebook API needs the curl PHP extension. All you need to do is to change the settings in the php.ini file.

Search the file for "extension=php_curl". Uncomment that line by removing the semi-colon infront of it. That should work!

Answer (score 0):

Open phpini file and uncomment the below curl extension. Then restart your wamp server.This work fine.

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```