# Facebook needs the CURL extension

Tags: php, facebook, curl, 64-bit, wamp

I'm trying to run my facebook php application on my apache server, on a new machine **with Windows 64bit**. As mentioned in the title, the error given is **Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension**. I have uncommented the line extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini and there is no problem in SublimeText, however when I try accessing my localhost, the error is thrown.
I've been looking a bit in `base_facebook.php`, where the error is thrown:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
  throw new Exception('Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.');
}
```

I've been looking on the internet and tried a lot of sites, including a topic with the same problem on stackoverflow:[Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8465586/1786117).
There is a comment about this problem with **WAMP 64bit**, and I tried the link with the fix, but nothing useful- seems like it has changed since.
Does anyone have the same issue? Any idea how to solve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and replace php_curl.dll with http://www.mediafire.com/?3ay381k3cq59cm2 had the same issue today lol
p.s: To the one who gave me a -1 I took the download link directly from http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ 
Please read what I have mentioned : **HAD THIS ISSUE *TODAY*!!!** and it worked.

Comment: I don't think I'd ever install a .dll off MediaFire. Eep.

Comment: I didn't -1, but I think it was done because they were not sure if that file is trustworthy.

Comment: @BujancaMihai: Make sure to virus scan the download first :)

Comment: @Bujanca Mihai:have you uncommented in the php.ini the curl library under wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini and restarted the server?

Comment: @KA_lin yes, I did.Both in php and apache directories

Comment: @Bujanca Mihai: So you have uncommented in both dirs and copied the php_curl.dll in the php/php[version]/ext/ with a server restart and still nothing? If so try stopping all services and make sure you run wamp with admin privileges...

Comment: I looked upon the other links here and found one that worked for me. Thanks http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](http://pinoyscreencast.net/fixing-wampserver-curl-extension-on-a-64bit-windows-7/) worked for me. Very straight forward too.